# I can't install Unity 3d via Unity Hub

Tags: 18.10, unity3d

I succesffuly installed Unity Hub 2.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.
In Unity Hub, I select Unity 2019.2. I also select "Android Build Support", "Android SDK", "Open JDK" and "Unity Documentation". Unity Hub downoloads all these files completly. But when it tries to install them, it crashes. And I lose all the files. I did it twice but it's the same result.

1. How can I can I fix it?
2. Which folder must I choose to Install Unity on Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL & thus off-topic on this site unless the question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  The only supported upgrade for 18.10 is to 19.04, which reaches EOL on thusday (23-Jan-2020) when you'll need to re-install. Use a LTS release if you need longer than 9 months of supported life.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 18.04. I forgot. Excuse me. I have also edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check file permissions on the destination directory. Make your user the owner with the command:

```
sudo chmod -R user:user /opt/unity
```